# Buttons won't work while the content is scrolling

Tags: react-native

I'm testing our app and can't solve this problem with our developers.

On the app page, there are top bar, tab bar and scrolling content.

When the content is scrolling, the top bar button, (back, add to fav, etc) just won't work.

It makes the app seem slow when using it.

(Sometimes your finger already left the screen, but the content is still slowing down scrolling)

I tried Facebook and airbnb, and either of them has this issue.

[See screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ccvlx.png)